# "Page not found" after clicking a row, but no error showed up in console

Tags: directus

My operation steps:

1. Change a table's PK from column A to column B, where A's `directus_fields.special = uuid`, and B is also a FK.
2. Drop column A.
3. Remove all records related to column A in Directus meta tables, like `directus_fields`.
4. Restart Directus.
5. In Directus GUI, navigate to the table and click on one row.
6. The "Page not found" error shows up, but no error in console where Directus is running.
   Could anyone give me some hints about where could go wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exactly look like a stack overflow question, but sounds like it should be a bug report on the repository.

Comment: I did. But no response so far...

Comment: Not every bug registered can be responded to immediately. If you would like to expedite any fixes, you're more than welcome to contact Monospace, the Directus parent company, and sponsor the development of fixing it in a timely fashion. Otherwise, you'll have to wait for any fixes. The issue you've raised here, isn't really something I believe can be answered by StackOverflow users as it sounds like a product bug.